# HTML5 Motion detection, grabbing and scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have followed a couple of tutorials (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-motion-detection.html, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/) and spliced the two together to create a game (https://github.com/gazzwi86/HTML5-Motion-Detection).  While I have a few things to work out with the blending to improve the quality of the detection, I was wondering how I would go about detecting grabbing and swipe gestures, say for navigating a web page.

Could you point me in the direction of some examples or outline the principles so that I may try it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go for it. It would require huge processing on client side to be quite good detection.

You can simply track moving objects(like hand) with some threshold(you can simply blur to get rid of noise). The background of user mostly will stay the same, so you can ignore it too.
Then convert image to black and white and try to have your moving object as one polygon.

What I would go to experiment after - set up a little neural network and train it myself by moving my hand.

Well that's just my 2 cents on how I would try to implement it. It would be really nice to hear from you later how did you do that and what the results are :)